# How Can I Send Data to the Action Filter after Execution of the controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, tempdata, custom-action-filter

The following is my action in the controller. I need to pass `ProductId` and `Quantity` to the filter `SessionCheck`. Is there any other way besides `TempData`?

```cs
[SessionCheck]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(int ProductId, int Quantity)
{
    try
    {
        //my code here 

        return RedirectToAction("Cart");
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

And the following is my action filter:

```cs
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
  // my code here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. So far as I'm aware, it's not possible to call the parameters *directly* from your filter—even though you can retrieve *metadata* about them via the [`ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor.getparameters?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ActionDescriptor_GetParameters) method.

#### Source Values

You can, however, access these values directly from their *source* collection using either [`RequestContext.RouteData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.requestcontext.routedata?view=netframework-4.8), or the [`RequestContext.HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.requestcontext.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Routing_RequestContext_HttpContext)’s [`Request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontextbase.request?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpContextBase_Request) property, which can retrieve data from the [`Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase.form?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequestBase_Form), [`QueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase.querystring?view=netframework-4.8), or other request collections. All of these are properties off of the [`ActionExecutedContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionexecutedcontext?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

#### Example

So, for example, if your values are being retrieved from the form collection—which I assume might be the case, since this is an `[HttpPost]` action—your code might look something like:

```cs
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
    Int32.TryParse(request.Form.Get("ProductId"), out var productId);
    Int32.TryParse(request.Form.Get("Quantity"), out var quantity);
}
```

#### Validation

Keep in mind that, technically, your `ActionFilterAttribute` can be applied to any number of actions, so you should be aware of that and not *assume* that these parameters will be available. You can use the [`ActionDescriptor.ActionName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor.actionname?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ActionDescriptor_ActionName) property to validate the context, if necessary:

```cs
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals(nameof(MyController.AddToCart)) 
    {
        //Retrieve values
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can use the [`ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor.getparameters?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ActionDescriptor_GetParameters) method mentioned above to simply evaluate if the parameters exist, regardless of what the name of the action is.

#### Caveats

There are some limitations to this approach. Most notably:

1. It won't be able to retrieve the values of internal calls to the action, and
2. It won't execute any model binding, which could be an issue for more sophisticated objects.

#### Other Frameworks

You specify ASP.NET MVC. For anyone reading this who's using ASP.NET Core, the class libraries are a bit different, and offer some additional functionality (such as `TryGetValue()` for calls to the `HttpRequest` methods). In addition, it also provides access to the `BoundProperties` collection, which *may* provide additional options—though I haven't dug into those data yet to confirm.

Comment: Thank you, it worked I used Int32.TryParse(request.QueryString.Get("ProductId"), out var productId); 
Thanks a lot.